# Is it a good idea to change metatag keywords in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags

I want to change the metatag keywords in html head in order to match every page content dynamically. 
but changing if with jquery, when the page has been already loaded sounds to me senseless. 
Will the search site recognize the change? Or will it keep the old keywords meta tag? 
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Mostly a search engine (I assume that is what you a worried about) doesn’t load any JavaScript when crawling. That being said, a search engine won’t update entries for a site when you visit it. Hence, it does not make any sense for me to update meta tags for this goal.

Comment: I believe that once the page is loaded it does not make senses because they are for search engines to use.

Comment: Where do you get the data from in jquery? ajax?

Comment: The designer who is building the page will create a hidden h3 tag that will contain the page title and keywords that I shoud extract and change in meta tags of the page using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Despite some comments to the contrary, Search Engine Bots do, in fact, load javascript. They typically utilize headless browsing to replicate the user experience as much as possible. [A simple google search will confirm this](https://www.google.com/search?q=do%20search%20engines%20load%20javascript&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS702US702&oq=do%20search%20engines%20load%20javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57.9516j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Meta information, such as keywords, are loaded only once per page crawl, however. While this does depend on the bot, the standard behavior is pretty clear. Changing this information in the middle of a crawl can actually hurt your results quite a bit. There is one possible caveat:

Search Engine Bots are aware of and pay attention to the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History). If your site is a single-page app that utilizes ajax and the History API to mimic multiple pages, then you could **potentially** load different meta tags and the bot might be aware. If, however, it is a standard multi-page site that simply changes the meta tags after load, then the bot will not really care.